# Cannot pass immutable value of type 'NSLayoutConstraint' as inout argument

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, inout

I try to reassign an referecend NSLayoutConstraint.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        exchangeConstraint(&myConstraint)
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func exchangeConstraint(_ constraint: inout NSLayoutConstraint) {
        let spacing = constraint.constant
        view.removeConstraint(constraint)
        constraint = view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anotherView.topAnchor, constant: spacing)
        view.addConstraint(constraint)
    }
}
```

But here it gives me the error:

```
exchangeConstraint(&myConstraint)
-------------------^
Cannot pass immutable value of type 'NSLayoutConstraint' as inout argument
```

What i don't understand is why it says immutable value, whereas the constraint is declared as a variable, not a constant.

Comment: Constraints don't work like that. You need to remove the old constraint and install a new one (you can modify the constant property but you don't need an inout parameter for that). You should have a very good reason to use inout parameters anyway. It is better for the function to return a new constraint if that is what you want.

Comment: yes, currently to keep my code running i do it as you suggest. so `myConstraint = doSomething(myConstraint)`. I just don't like using the variable two times in a line for one thing. I hope for a cleaner way.

Comment: That is the cleaner way compared to using a side effect (inout parameter). As I said, you need to remove the existing constraint anyway before you add a new one, if you don't have the reference to the exisiting constraint, it will be hard to do that.

Comment: `NSLayoutConstraint` is reference type anyway. Why do you pass it as an `inout` parameter?

Comment: Ok, i updated my example. I want to keep the constraint variable, but change its content. So i remove it from the view, assign a new value to the variable and add it again.

Comment: Not before a computer, so I can‘t check. But I suspect this is because the var is an implicitly unwrapped optional. Does something change if you declare the constraint explicitely optional?

Comment: To elaborate, easiest would probably be to change the parameter type of the exchangeConstraint func so it takes an optional. This should get rid of the implicit unwrap

Comment: Or you could call it as `exchangeConstraint(&myConstraint!)` – `myConstraint!` produces an l-value that can be used with `inout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by simply declaring the `constraint` parameter as an explicitly unwraped `NSLayoutConstraint`.

```
func exchangeConstraint(_ constraint: inout NSLayoutConstraint!) {
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a project where I use it: https://github.com/truffls/compatible-layout-anchors-ios